# How do I use the contents of a SQL column as a database name in another select's from statement?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database that contains a table. wherein one of the columns in that table is [database_name].  I want to use the contents of that column to link to a table in another database and return the contents of one of the columns in that table.

Here's what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT  t1.col1
       ,t1.col2
       ,t1.col3
       ,t1.database_name
       ,t1.cust_id
       ,(SELECT t2.ordered_on
         FROM [t1.database_name].[dbo].[order_info] t2
         WHERE t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id
        ) as order_placed_on
FROM [my_database].[dbo].[table1] t1
ORDER BY order_placed_on DESC
```

The problem, of course, is that SQL Server takes the [t1.data_source] thing literally, and doesn't substitute the CONTENTS of the column t1.data_source.

I also tried declaring a variable @databaseName and using @databaseName.[dbo].[order_info] but I can't seem to get that to work either. Here's the example of that non-working code:

```
DECLARE @databaseName nvarchar(50)
SELECT  t1.col1
       ,t1.col2
       ,t1.col3
       ,t1.database_name
       ,@databaseName = t1.database_name
       ,t1.cust_id
       ,(SELECT t2.ordered_on
         FROM @databaseName.[dbo].[order_info] t2
         WHERE t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id
        ) as order_placed_on
FROM [my_database].[dbo].[table1] t1
ORDER BY order_placed_on DESC
```

That code gives me

> Incorrect syntax near '.'"

Clearly it doesn't like the `@databaseName.[dbo].[order_info]` format.  And if I add brackets around the @dataSource variable, so it looks like `[@databaseName].[dbo].[order_info]` I get a "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations." error.  No clue why.  `select @variableName = column_name` is precisely how you assign data to a variable in a select statement.  So I have no idea what's going on there...  Something is getting it confused, but I don't know what, and at this point, I just need this stupid thing to work.

Anyway, I just need to know how to make SQL Server substitute the *CONTENTS* of the column for the column name (or variable name) in that second select's from statement.

Comment: no the databsename has to exists, why not use dynamic sql`? which is the onl yway btw

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL. T-SQL isn't a scripting language, you can't use a variable, or column's name, to replace something that needs to be a literal (like an object name).

Comment: Why do you *need* to do this? Such a requirement normally means a larger design flaw.

Comment: Refer to this question on [table name as variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/515768/table-name-as-a-variable.html). The approach will be very similar and require the use of dynamic sql. Note that three-part names (database.schema.object) should generally be avoided as it makes your code very difficult to move between environments. Beware your assumptions. Your table has multiple rows and each can have a different value in column database_name. You might not use it that way but your schema supports it.